# Handling imbalanced data in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, unbalanced-classes, keras

I have noticed that we can provide class weights in model training through Keras APIs. However, I could not locate a clear documentation on how this weighting works in practice. 
Say I have two classes with sample size $1000$ (for class $0$) and $10000$ (for class $1$). Now, to balance this how should I assign class weights?

**Option1:** class_weight = {0 : 10., 1: 1.}
   **Option2:** class_weight = {0 : 1., 1: 10.}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's option 1, you want to give greater weight for the less frequent class, so that

$$
w_0 n_0 = w_1 n_1
$$

where $w_i$ are weights and $n_i$ counts. Greater weight leads to greater importance, so single case with greater weight may be worth more then multiple cases with smaller weights.